# Redirect if hostname is incorrect with Node

Tags: node.js, redirect, iis, https

We have a site hosted on **IIS using http (port 80)**
and we have a new site hosted on **Node using https (port 443)**

For reasons I won't go into too much, we can't use IISNode to run all websites on IIS.

This setup works unless someone uses https to reach one of the IIS hosted websites.

to reproduce:

http://nameprintgraphics.com -> IIS website

https://npgcloud.com -> Node website

if you type in https://nameprintgraphics.com however, you go to the node website. I want to prevent this behaviour. Since node is listening to port 443, is there a way to validate the hostname and if it's incorrect, redirect the user to http.

I know this is a bit of a convoluted way to fix things, but please work with me to find an interim solution to this problem. IISNode is preventing a legacy silverlight app from working in IIS for reasons I have yet to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check `req.headers.host` in your node app and if it matches, then simply send a redirect response immediately? For example:

```
// You may/may not want to append the `req.url` to the destination as well
res.writeHead(302, { Location: 'http://nameprintgraphics.com' });
res.end();
```

Comment: I didn't use this technique because it's doing this for multiple sites, not just nameprintgraphics.com

Comment: Did you try having IIS do the SSL/TLS termination and just have a reverse (http) proxy to the node process instead?